# Room Android, select on two tables

Tags: java, select, embedded, android-room

I am new to Room and I'm struggling with it.
I would like to do a simple select over two tables named Project and Tasks. These are the two classes and a third to link them :

```
    @Entity
    public class Project {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        private final long id;
        @NonNull
        private final String name;
        @ColorInt
        private final Integer color;
       }
    
    @Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Project.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "projectId"))
    public class Task {
    
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        private long idTask;
    
        // clé commune
        private long projectId;
    
        @NonNull
        private String nameTask;
    
        public long creationTimestamp;
    // constructor, getters, setters
       }
    
    public class TaskWithProject {
        @Embedded public Project project;
        @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "projectId")
        public Task task;
    }
```

I have tried many things in my Dao class. Here are two of those :

```
    @Dao
    public interface TaskDao {
    (...)
    
    // Solution 1
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Task t JOIN Project p ON t.projectId = p.id")
        LiveData<List<TaskWithProject>> getTaskWithProject();
    
    // Solution 2 from https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Task")
    LiveData<List<TaskWithProject>> getTaskWithProject();
```

My database is populated with these datas (no problem in the database inspector) :

```
    projectDao.insertProject(new Project(0, "Projet Tartampion", 0xFFEADAD1));
                    projectDao.insertProject(new Project(0, "Projet Lucidia", 0xFFB4CDBA));
                    projectDao.insertProject(new Project(0, "Projet " + "Circus", 0xFFA3CED2));
                    taskDao.insertTask(new Task(0, 1, "Task 1 - Tartampion"));
                    taskDao.insertTask(new Task(0, 1, "Task 2 - Tartampion"));
                    taskDao.insertTask(new Task(0, 2, "Task 1 - Lucidia"));
```

I get the data with this function :

```
    public LiveData<List<TaskViewStateItem>> getAllTasks() {
            return Transformations.map(repository.getTaskWithProject(), tasks -> {
                List<TaskViewStateItem> liststateitems = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (TaskWithProject t : tasks) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "getAllTasks: "+ t.toString());
                        liststateitems.add(new TaskViewStateItem(t.task.getIdTask(), t.task.getNameTask(), t.project.getName(), t.project.getColor(), t.task.getCreationTimestamp()));
                    }
                }
                return liststateitems;
            });
        }
```

With the solution 1 above I have 3 entries as expected but with a duplicate one.

```
    I/Log ViewModel: getAllTasks: TaskWithProject{project=Project{id=1, name='Projet Tartampion', color=-1385775}, task=Task{idTask=2, projectId=1, nameTask='Task 2 - Tartampion', creationTimestamp=1634723235}}
    I/Log ViewModel: getAllTasks: TaskWithProject{project=Project{id=1, name='Projet Tartampion', color=-1385775}, task=Task{idTask=2, projectId=1, nameTask='Task 2 - Tartampion', creationTimestamp=1634723235}}
        getAllTasks: TaskWithProject{project=Project{id=2, name='Projet Lucidia', color=-4928070}, task=Task{idTask=3, projectId=2, nameTask='Task 1 - Lucidia', creationTimestamp=1634723235}}
```

The solution 2 does not compile

```
    error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (com.cleanup.todoc.model.TaskWithProject).
        LiveData<List<TaskWithProject>> getTaskWithProject();
                                        ^
```

I have no idea what I did wrong. So thank you very much for any help you can give me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your TaskWithProject class has the project embedded, then it expects, to get the columns for the project and then build the task(s) from that and hence when you use `SELECT * FROM Task` it doesn't have the pertinent columns (with the join it does BUT may not work as expected).

- really TaskWithProject is ProjectWithTask.

So either use `SELECT * FROM project` or use a POJO with the Task Embedded and the Project as the @Relation (with `SELECT * FROM task`).

Comment: With the 1st solution and the class like this `TaskWithProject {
        @Embedded public Project project;
        @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "projectId")
        public List<Task> tasks;
    }` I have this error `Compilation of classes com.cleanup.todoc.database.Dao.TaskDao_Impl$3 requires its nest mates com.cleanup.todoc.database.Dao.TaskDao_Impl$5 (unavailable) to be on program or class path.(Classes com.cleanup.todoc.database.Dao.TaskDao_Impl, (...) from the same nest are on class path).`
Do you know why?

Comment: @Emmcy no BUT I suspect that you might have to do a clean or rebuild, the _Impl classes are the ones generated by room. Saying that there is no need/use doing the join as Room gets the @Relation via separate queries all it needs (and uses) is the data to build the Embedded in fact joins, if any column names are the same, can cause unexpected results (I believe it may get the value of the last column of any that are the same names). Good to see that you have `List<Task> tasks;` was going to say that you probably want that so you get all the tasks with a project.

Comment: I have changed the class name from TaskWithProject to ProjectWithTasks and the error has gone away (maybe it has forced some kind of rebuild). Thank you so much for your very clear explanation.